# UINavigationBar jumps from Large Title to small one while pushing to UIViewController with embedded UITableView iOS 11

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

As it is said from the title, when I try to push `UIViewController` with `UITableView` in it and show LargeTitle, it shows for the very first moment and then hides to the small one.

*It's weird but this bug is reproduced on **4 inch** devices only.*

[image]

This behavior is seems to be an **Apple's bug**.

Any other workarounds or nuances I missed?
Thanks for any suggestions.

[**Uploaded test project (GitHub)**](https://github.com/Sander-Kornev/LargeTitleBug)

Comment: This is really an annoying problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workarounds I found so far

1. Attach `UITableView`'s top to `SafeArea's` top, but this approach lose effect of transparent `UINavigationBar` and `LargeTitle` collapses very fast on scrolling
2. Use `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController+UITableView`, but this approach loses known flexibility. It's not trivial to hide tableView or add subviews.
3. `pushViewController` without animation

Comment: The same issue occurs when your view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Also, please don't advise others to avoid `UITableViewController`.  If your design presents organized rows of information, and observes Apple's human interface guidelines, you probably *should* use it, and modify your design to make the most of it.

If you "roll your own" (`UIViewController+UITableView`) you'll either have to continually add code to handle the increasing number of behaviors `UITableViewController` gives you for free, or ship an app that doesn't feel like it belongs on the platform.

Comment: How do you "attach to SafeArea's top"?

Comment: @ErikAigner there are 2 ways to do so: 1. you can activate Safe area checkmark in File Inspector in Interface Builder and make constraint from table view top to safe area top, or 2. in code something like view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: safe area layout guide wouldn't work backward towards lower than iOS 11? The table view will end up having some empty space above the first row

Answer (score 0):

Just set a table view header of non-zero height for the TableView.